# Find people absent from the country for a certain time

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has the "document number" field, the type of flow (entering or leaving the country), date of birth, and the date the flow occurred.

Knowing that a person can leave or enter several times a year, how can I list those people (by their document number) of legal age (>=21yo) who were out of the country in a specific interval of the year (for example: between May 1, 2021 and August 1, 2021)?

ideally a syntax according to postgresql

EDIT: Info complement

Table: flows

| id_flow | doc_number | brth_date | flow_type | flow_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1999-05-01 | in | 2020-06-01 |
| 2 | 123 | 1999-05-01 | out | 2020-10-30 |
| 3 | 222 | 1988-01-09 | out | 2021-01-01 |
| 4 | 180 | 1993-11-15 | out | 2021-06-16 |
| 5 | 222 | 1988-01-09 | in | 2021-10-30 |
| 6 | 223 | 2009-09-05 | out | 2020-06-04 |
| 7 | 223 | 2009-09-05 | in | 2021-12-04 |

where dates are yyy-MM-DD and should return:

| doc_number |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 222 |

because these people were out in the whole interval and has legal age.

Answer (score -1):

I think , you need sql statement like this:

```
select distinct person
from
(select person, max(date) as LEAVE_DATE from documentnumber where date<'2021-05-01' and flow='leaving' group by person ) A 
JOIN 
(select person,MAX(date) as ENTER_DATE from documentnumber where date<'2021-08-01' and flow='entering' group by person) B ON A.PERSON=B.PERSON 
where A.LEAVE_DATE>B.ENTER_DATE
```

Comment: Don't think this does what OP wants. It appears it's probably missing these things: "*list those people (**"by their document number**)*" and "*of legal age (>=21yo)*".